# Rectangular inside circle responsive with contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make rectangular inside the circle on the left , when im resizing the screen of the website the shapes moving out and the texts checking out from the shapes , any ways to make texts and shapes responsive to all screens
The code : https://codepen.io/enespro/pen/rNWmLvP

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="circle">
          <h3 class="mt-4">Bzns Monster School<br><span style="font-size: 20px; color: #DDDD;">From Zero To Hero</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='rect-box'>
      </div>
      <div class='rect-content'>
        <div class="content">
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur<br> sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod<br> tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary ml-1">Read More</button>
      </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using percentages to set size and position, changing browser window size is going to mess up the layout. You can change sizes to px in the css but you will not get the responsiveness you are after, so you can set css layout for screen width using media or viewpoint, lots of resources out there, but good place to start is  [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) or other methods here: [https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design)

Comment: If you can't even replicate your problem in your "codepen" nor in the snippet.. How do you expect us to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your code there's a lot of position absolute that will just drive you crazy in long term to maintain that code. What about using the magic of flex, instead? :)
I rewrote your code here below. Check it clicking on "Run Code Snippet" to see it in action.

I suggest on the mobile to separate the banner from the circle to make it responsive and readable.
Enjoy!

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle span {
  color: #fff;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .circle {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .rectangle {  
    padding: 30px 0 30px 220px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='circle'><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
  <div class='rectangle'>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , Any ways to make the cricle responsive with rectangular one ?